# Momentjs compare dates

Tags: angular, momentjs

I am using moment.js DATE library in my angular application. For some reason the date that is selected is shown wrong.
I have FROM and TO dates.
Both FROM and TO are defaulted to 03/2023
When I change FROM date: I get the updated value (say 01/2000)
When I change TO date : I get the updated value (say 01/2005) and also FROM date value is being modified to my defaulted value 03/2023.
As such when I am tying to find difference in months between selected dates, i get wrong value and sometimes -ve

```
// called when FROM date is changed
  getBeginMthYr(bDate: Moment) {
    this.selBeginDate = bDate;
    this.selectedDates = [];
    this.selectedDates.push(this.convertDateString(this.selBeginDate, this.selEndDate));
  }

// called when TO date is changed
  getEndMthYr(endDate: Moment) {
    this.selEndDate = endDate;
    this.selectedDates = [];
    this.selectedDates.push(this.convertDateString(this.selBeginDate, this.selEndDate));
  }
  
  convertDateString(beginDate: Moment, endDate: Moment) {

    let dmths = endDate.diff(beginDate, 'months');
    let i: number;
    let dateStr: string = '';
    if (this.validRangeDate) {
      dateStr = beginDate.format('YYYYM');
      for (i = 0; i < dmths; i++) {
        let stepDate = beginDate.add(1, 'M');
        dateStr = dateStr + ',' + stepDate.format('YYYYM');
      }
    }
    return dateStr;
  }
  
  validRangeDate(beginDate: Moment, endDate: Moment): boolean { 
    if (endDate.diff(beginDate, 'months') < 0) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you create a simple sandbox or a fiddle may be?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is happening because Moment.js uses mutable objects.
So when you modify a date, it modifies the original object.

So beginDate is changed with the line:

```
let stepDate = beginDate.add(1, 'M');
```

Instead you can clone your date:

```
let stepDate = beginDate.clone().add(1, 'M');
```

More details can be found [here](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/03-manipulating/01-add/)

Comment: thanks for the information, If I comment this line, will it work?

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can clone your date `let stepDate = beginDate.clone().add(1, 'M');`

Comment: your solution picks the correct date. But when I am trying to find all dates between begin and end dates selected , using let dmths = endDate.diff(beginDate, 'months');, it is giving me incorrect months and when I try to debug, endDate and beginDate are not having the correct values